# Passing parameter from for loop to multiline sh in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I have groovy jenkins pipeline step and I want to pass for loop value as parameter to multiline `sh` script in loop. But parameter is not getting passed.

Or if theres a better way to add step in jenkins stage?

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {

    sh '''
       cd terraform/
       terraform init
       terraform workspace select ${elements[i]}-${envtype}
       terraform plan -var-file="./configs/${elements[i]}/var.tf"
    '''
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `"""` instead of `'''`?

Comment: Sweet lord jesus Thanks @Opal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you should use `"""` instead of `'''`. `'''` is triple *single* quoted `String` and [doesn't support](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string) interpolation.

Comment: Is it possible to get return value of only last sh statement from above?

Comment: What do you mean? From which line would you like to get the result?

Comment: from `terraform plan`

Answer (score 1):

You need a [triple double quoted string](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string). You are using a [triple single quoted string](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string). Any single quoted string in Groovy does not feature String interpolation, so `'''${i}'''` prints `${i}`, while `"""${i}"""` prints `3` (if `i = 3`).